# tensorflow set pre-weights gives dimension error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm a tensorflow newbie. I want to build a vgg-16 network then use that to modify the network.

So far I'm stucked at layer 1 here is what I have:

```
def conv_layer(bottom, name, kernel):
    with tf.variable_scope(name):

        #net weight dictionary from caffe's version of caffe
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(net.weights[name+'/w'], kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

        conv_biases = tf.constant(net.weights[name+'/b'], name="biases")
        bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, conv_biases)

        relu = tf.nn.relu(bias)
        return relu

kernel1_1= tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 3, 64], dtype=tf.float32, stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
conv_layer(tf.cast(image_batch, tf.float32), "conv1_1", kernel1_1)
```

The error I get is:

```
 Dimensions must be equal, but are 64 and 3 for 'conv1_1_15/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [3,3,3,64], [3,3,3,64]
```

This makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what net.weights contains, but assuming that has weights for your kernel it seems to me that you should be assigning those to the kernel variable.

```
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(net.weights[name+'/w'], kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

should be

```
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(bottom, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

and once your network definition is done, you assign the weights to kernels and biases.